# Unity: The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers

Tags: java, 3d

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

---

- The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
- should follow the instructions here:                                       *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
- to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
- Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *

---

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7629)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6976)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:257)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

---

- The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
- should follow the instructions here:                                       *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
- to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
- Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
- https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *

---

```
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzacy.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.0.0:20)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.0.0:1)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7624)
... 10 more
```

I created a game for Android and when adding ads from Admob it turns out this error i tried to change the file androidmanifest.xml but without success

Here's my androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
<application>
    <uses-library android:required="false" 
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-046593468034~534353564574676" />
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: i edited posts add AndroidManifest.xml